# How do I put a Brown Paper Ticket ticket sale button on our CiviCRM main page

Tags: button

The website for our performing arts organization got handed off to me and I have very little CiviCRM experience.

Where in the user controls do I put the Brown Paper Tickets code that create a usable Button on our website? You help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if this is too vague and possibly off topic.

Answer (score 1):

welcome. you may need to dig out some more info to help folk here help you. I for one had to google to find that Brown Paper tickets is a third party event ticketing systems. GIven that civicrm has CiviEvent for its own event management system, your question may not be civicrm specific rather than a CMS question. Or it may be that your site has some customisation for this.